# CSS Media Queries on Bootstrap not working on iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, css, media

I'm using `Bootstrap` as my responsive framework.

I have got my own style sheet underneath the Bootstrap CSS files, with own `Media Queries` in it... but when it comes to viewing my web page on my `iPhone 4`, the `heading` and `tags` dont change to conform the way i want to on my phone.

Here is a snippet of the way my code looks:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i set the `Media Queries` as follow.....

```
  /* Large desktop */
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

  /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

  /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
  @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

  /* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

I've already cleared the cache on my iPhone, but it's still not working

Answer (score 8):

You may have missed the tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

before your imports.

Please refer to the documentation and ensure you followed all the steps:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: forgot to write that in.. declare the viewport... thats not the problem.. really stuck and dont no where to go from here... the nav shrinks to a smalled one with the menu button.. but my heading and text and all stay large even when i declare them smaller in the relavent media query

Comment: managed to solve the question my self.. missing some tags.... another question though.. when i view my site on my phone when i zoom in my css all messes up... how can i stop this from happening.. thanks

Comment: You should probably post that on a different question. And you should DEFINITELY post an ANSWER with the solution you found, to help future visitors with your same problem.